# Best way to solve conflict between EclipseLink @Version Timestamp-Field and DB2

Tags: java, db2, eclipselink

In the current project I'm working on, we are using **EclipseLink as JPA-Provider**. In the background is a **DB2-database**. 
We want to **introduce "Optimistic Locking"** with the **restriction only** using **Timestamp-fields**. Furthermore, these timestamp fields are CURRENT TIMESTAMP fields, so when updating an entity, the CURRENT TIMESTAMP field updates the value itself. This is necessary to guarantee the reliability of the whole system.

When annotating the attribute of an entity with @Version, I get the following error message:  
 
*Internal Exception: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: THE SQL STATEMENT IS NOT SUPPORTED. SQLCODE=-142, SQLSTATE=42612, DRIVER=4.22.29 

Error Code: -142 

Call: VALUES CURRENT TIMESTAMP 

Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="VALUES CURRENT TIMESTAMP")
                at  
org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl$1.handleException(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:767)
                at  
 org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.handleException(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:275)
                […]*

Note: I only get this error message when using the mentioned annotation.
 
 
 
My research resulted in the following:

1. **Internal Exception**: com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: 
   --> A StaleConnectionException is an exception that is generated by the WebSphere Application Server database connection code when a JDBC driver returns a fatal error from a connection request or operation. In WebSphere Application Server, the StaleConnectionException is issued when the database vendor issues an exception indicating that a connection currently in the connection pool is no longer valid. ( https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/205910/how-to-resolve-the-staleconnectionexception-in-web/ )
2. THE SQL STATEMENT IS NOT SUPPORTED. SQLCODE=-142, 
   --> An SQL statement was detected that is **not supported by the database**. The statement might be valid for other IBM® relational database products or it **might be valid in another context**. For example, statements **such as VALUES** and SIGNAL or RESIGNAL SQLSTATE can be used only in certain contexts, such as in a trigger body or in an SQL Procedure.  ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n142.html )
3. SQLSTATE=42612,  
   --> Seems to be internal, nothing for my relevance

After getting more into the topic, I came across the following link, which appears as the most encouraging so far: 
https://www.idug.org/p/fo/et/thread=36380  
In summary, the suggested way is to extend org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DB2MainframePlatform and manipulate the generated SQL-statement.

My expectation is, that there should be a better way, since this should be a standard-case for the framework. If not, is there an more proper/better way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's necessary to tell your middleware which flavour of Db2 syntax to use before it emits SQL. The SQL Syntax varies between hardware-platforms ( z/OS,  i-series,  Linux/Unix/Windows) so always indicate *which* version you are actually using.

Comment: Optimistic locking is checking the value of the columns you are attempting to change before the update and only updating when the fields are still the same.  With that said.  I think there's a parenthesis missing values (current timestamp).  Good luck

Comment: What is the actual SQL that is issued and the stack for the exception? That doesn't look like a complete SQL statement. Could you have modified your platform class and set this string in the query it uses to get the DB timestamp?  Check for setTimestampQuery and the target platform class being used for your DB